# Description box not aligned properly in review rejects

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Description box comes out of the windows as screenshot.Is that a part of design change  ? I have seen that frequently while reviewing .

[image]

Comment: What browser? What OS? What URL?

Comment: Repro-ed in IE11/Win7 x64 cc @Oded (zoom on 100%)

Comment: @Oded same in Chrome Windows 7.

Comment: There is `.popup textarea {
    width: 100%;
}` that takes precedence over `textarea.custom-reason-text {
    width: 600px;
}`

Comment: actually it was seen in : Windows7 , Chrome browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is collateral damage from fixing textareas for FireFox on linux in other popups.

A fix has been pushed and will be in out in the next build.

Comment: ohh great..let stackoverflow always be damage free :) ..